# jQuery find closest ul and check only those inputs

Tags: jquery, find, closest

I have a check all and it is working but the problem is i have multiple rows with the same check all function and i only want that the check-all only works by the clostest ul with the inputs but how can i do that?

The JS

```
        $('.css-margin').each( function() {
            $(this).val(s);
        });
```

The HTML

```
<div class="css-margin-padding">
<div class="check-all">
    <span class="dashicons dashicons-lock css-checkall margin-checkall"></span>
    Link all values.
</div>

<ul>
    <li><label>Top</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="1"></li>
    <li><label>Right</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="2"></li>
    <li><label>Bottom</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="3"></li>
    <li><label>Left</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="4"></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work for you..!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.margin-checkall').parent().next('ul').find('li').each(function() {
     $(this).find('.css-margin').val('Text for test');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check-all">
    <span class="dashicons dashicons-lock css-checkall margin-checkall"></span>
    Link all values.
</div>

<ul>
    <li><label>Top</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="1"></li>
    <li><label>Right</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="2"></li>
    <li><label>Bottom</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="3"></li>
    <li><label>Left</label><input type="text" class="css-margin" name="" tabindex="4"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, now only one changed... all the inputs in the closest ul need to link. So when you fill in one input the other 3 will change also. It was working but because i have more check-alls and lists on one page when you then checked one all the inputs linked with each other and i only whant the the check-all of each box link with the closest ul inputs. (hope you understand)

Comment: Then you need to get the id of every input, if you want some dynamic value in every input.

Comment: How do you mean? It is all working when i have one check-all div and one ul on a page. when i click the icon and fill in the number one in a input all the 4 inputs have 1 in them then. But when i have a other check-all and a ul list on the page and click on one of the 2 icons and fill in the number 1 in a input the all 8 inputs will have one and that is not how it needs to work.

Comment: Can you edit your question with full code please, I will improve my answer accordingly....?

Comment: [First Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opo1odmu/) [Second Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opo1odmu/1/) [Third Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opo1odmu/2/) [Fourth Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/opo1odmu/3/) Look there what you want...?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149137/discussion-between-rohit-sharma-and-maanstraat).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.margin-checkall.checked').parent().next().find('.css-margin').each(...)
```

This read as: Find Elements with class margin-checkall AND checked; Get the parent (div); get Next Element (ul); Find in it every element with class css-margin; And finally your each function